# Retrieve all 'has_many' related objects filtered by one instance in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two ActiveRecords Users and Posts:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post
end

class Post < MyBase
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I'm trying to get list of all users and **all** their posts.
However when running the following code, I get the users who has posts with id 1 or 2, but only these posts. I want to get these users with all their posts.
Any ideas how to do that?

`users = User.sorted.references([:posts]).includes([:posts]).where('posts.id=1' OR posts.id=2).all`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it, first get the user ids of posts with id 1 or 2, and then get all those users. There are other ways of course, but this at least should work for you.

```
user_ids = Post.where('id = 1 OR id = 2').pluck(:user_id)
users = User.where(id: user_ids)
```